# Solving $u_{yy} + 6u_y + 13u = 4e^{3y}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

> Solve the following PDE
>   $$\partial_{yy} u + \partial_y u + 3u = 4e^{3x}, \quad u = u(x, y).$$

What I get is the following but when verified it wasn't what I expected to be and didn't get the solution I wanted

can someone verify

$$u=v(x)e^{-3}\left(k\cos(2y)+w\sin(2y)+\frac1{10}e^3y\right)$$

Comment: @Harry49 *Strongly related* might be an understatement; this is a straightup duplicate.

Comment: Duplicate question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3533881/418542)

Answer (score 1):

$$u''+6u'+13u=4e^{3y}$$
The characteristic equation is
$$r^2+6r+13=0 \implies \Delta =36-4.13=-16$$
$$\implies S_r=\{-3 \pm 2i\}$$
The solution of the homogeneous equation is
$$u(x,y)=e^{-3y}(c_1(x)\cos (2y)+c_2(x) \sin (2y))$$
For the particular solution
$$u_p=Ae^{3y} \implies 9A+18A+13A=4 $$
$$\implies A=\frac 1 {10}$$
Finally:
$$u(x,y)=e^{-3y}(c_1(x)\cos (2y)+c_2(x) \sin (2y))+\frac 1 {10}e^{3y}$$